# ASP.NET MVC 4 Joining two tables

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have 2 tables one is **Issues** and other is **JiraAssignee**. Issues have column named `AssigneeID` and JiraAssignee consist of AssigeeID and AssigneeName. I need AssigneeName from there.

I have tried query but it won't return the value from `JiraAssignee` Table.

```
   public ActionResult COED()
    {
     var model = new SO_80.Models.Tables();
     string COED = "COED";

     model.Issue = db.Issues.Where(d => 
     model.JiraAssignee = (from d in db.Issues.Where(d => d.JiraIssueKey.Contains(COED)).ToList()
                              join j in db.JiraAssignees.ToList() on d.JiraAssigneeID equals j.ID
                              select new JiraAssignee() { DisplayName = j.DisplayName });
     return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Your `ToList()` calls are causing  the provider to run the queries independently and having LINQ to Objects actually handle the JOIN in memory of the client. I'm not convinced that is your issue though. Have you tried writing the query as raw SQL and executing that?

Comment: @siva.k Yes I have tried writing it in sql server management studio and it worked there. I am unable to write it in `homecontroller.cs`. Maybe i am doing something wrong in the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
public ActionResult COED()
    {
     var model = new SO_80.Models.Tables();
     string COED = "COED";
     Issue result = null;
     using (Entities db = new Entities())
            {
              result = (from d in db.Issues
                        join j in db.JiraAssignees on db.Issues equals j.ID 
                        where j.JiraIssueKey.ToLower().Trim().Contains(COED)
                        select d).FirstOrDefault();
            }
     return View(result);
    }
```

Comment: @Muneeb please upvote and accept this answer if this answer helps you, so people know this is the correct answer.